# Mysql Join non matching tables with one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to get all results from table 1 (Reports) and join the other two tables onto it (users) and (workorders)

Reports has keys relating to Users and Workorders but they are stored in csv values.
I am trying to peform something similar to this psuedo code

```
`SELECT * 
FROM reports 
LEFT JOIN users ON reports = (WHERE users.userID IN (reports.users))
LEFT JOIN workorders ON reports = (WHERE workorder.status IN (reports.filters) 
AND reports.reportid = 10
`
```

reports.users and reports.filters look like "1,2,3,4,5,6"

Comment: You should normalize your data so you don't have to match against a comma-separated list.

Comment: I am trying to make a custom reporting piece that alerts users when the workorder.status matches the filters and users that they chose. This table will be added to by many people and the script will be run every 5-10 minutes Wouldnt it be to slow/large so store every user/status combo that a user wants to be alerted to in seperate rows?

Comment: It should be faster, because it will be able to use indexes to match the filter, instead of string matching on every row. And it shouldn't be large, since you can store `report_users` and `report_filters` in separate tables -- you don't need every combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (meaning that `reports.users` and `reports.filters` are strings of comma-delimited values), you need the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function for this:

```
SELECT * from reports 
LEFT JOIN users ON FIND_IN_SET(users.userID, reports.users)
LEFT JOIN workorders ON FIND_IN_SET(workorder.status, reports.filters) 
  AND reports.reportid = 10
```